# How does numpy.where() work when input in the form numpy.where(array condition, array1, array2)?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, where-clause

I hope that somebody can provide some clarification on how the `numpy.where()` function works. After trying out several different inputs, I cannot wrap my head around it. Taking the first example below, the output of:

```
np.where([True,False],[1,0],[3,4])
```

is:

```
array([1, 4])
```

How exactly is the array of Boolean values being applied to the arrays `[1,0]` and `[3,4]` to yield the output?

Results of some additional testing are shown below:

```
import numpy as np

np.where([True,False],[1,0],[3,4])
Out[129]: array([1, 4])

np.where([True,False],[1,0],[6,4])
Out[130]: array([1, 4])

np.where([True,False],[1,0],[0,0])
Out[131]: array([1, 0])

np.where([True,False],[0,0],[0,0])
Out[132]: array([0, 0])

np.where([True,False],[1,0],[0,12])
Out[133]: array([ 1, 12])

np.where([True,False],[1,6],[4,12])
Out[134]: array([ 1, 12])

np.where([True,True],[1,6],[4,12])
Out[135]: array([1, 6])

np.where([False,False],[1,6],[4,12])
Out[136]: array([ 4, 12])

np.where([True,False],[1,0],[3,4])
Out[137]: array([1, 4])

np.where([True,True],[1,0],[3,4])
Out[138]: array([1, 0])

np.where([True,True],[1,0],[3,4])
Out[139]: array([1, 0])

np.where([True,False],[1,0],[3,4])
Out[140]: array([1, 4])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you give 3 arguments to `np.where` the first argument is the condition that decides if the corresponding value in the result is taken from the second argument (if the value in the condition is `True`) or from the third argument (if the value in the condition is `False`).

So when all values are `True` it will be a copy of the first argument, and if all values are `False` it will be a copy of the second argument. In case they are mixed it will be a combination.

Think of it as a more sophisticated version of:

```
def where(condition, x, y):
    result = []
    for idx in range(len(condition)):
        if condition[idx] == True:
            result.append(x[idx])
        else:
            result.append(y[idx])
    return result
```

That function is of course much slower (not even the fastest pure Python equivalent), it also doesn't support broadcasting or multidimensional arrays and the one-argument form but I hope it helps in understanding the 3 argument form of `np.where`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly addressed my confusion.